# problems with background when adding SVG image to the website

Tags: html, css, svg, transparency, imagebackground

I have svg image with transparent background (from inkscape, I have checked its transparency, I am 100% sure its transparent). When I add it to the website using , it automatically adds a white background, so it is no longer transparent. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read [ask] and post a [mre] of your code. We need to see your code in order to troubleshoot it :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the SVG file in Figma, if a white background appears remove it from the rest of the parts and save this edited one. Works all the time!